# Checking if a password is strong enough - Haskell vs procedural language

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I implemented a function in Python that checks if a password is strong enough. A password is strong enough if it passes 3 out of 5 checks. This is the Python function:

```
def is_valid(password):
    checks = {
        lambda x : True : 10,
        lambda x : x.isupper() : 2,
        lambda x : x.islower() : 2,
        lambda x : x.isdigit() : 2,
        lambda x : x in frozenset("~!@#$%^&*()-=_+[]{}<>?/\\`") : 2,
    }

    for c in password:
        for func in list(checks):
            if func(c):
                checks[func] -= 1
                if checks[func] == 0:
                    del checks[func]

        if len(checks) <= 2:
            return True

    return False
```

This function can operate on an infinite password if it is strong enough. If it's not, then the function will hang:

```
>>> is_valid(itertools.cycle("!!xxxxxxxx"))
True
>>> is_valid(itertools.cycle("UUxxxxxxxx"))
True
```

I woundered if I could implement the same function in Haskell in a more elegant way, so I came up with this solution:

```
isValid :: String -> Bool
isValid password =
  let
    checks = atLeast 10 password:map containsChars [isUpper, isLower, isSpecialChar, isDigit]
  in atLeast 3 $ filter (==True) checks
  where
    containsChars predicate = length (take 2 $ filter predicate password) == 2
    isSpecialChar c = isPunctuation c || isSymbol c
    atLeast n seq = length (take n seq) == n
```

This solution seems a bit more elegant but has a drawback over the procedural solution. If the password is infinite and does not have enough uppercase characters, the function will hang even if it passes the other conditions:

```
*Main Data.Char> isValid (cycle "UUxxxxxxxx")
True
*Main Data.Char> isValid (cycle "!!xxxxxxxx")
-- hangs
```

Is there a way to implement an elegant soultion in Haskell which doesn't have this drawback?

BTW: Is there something built-in in Haskell that I can use instead of the `atLeast` function that I implemented?

Comment: I'm curious; is 'infinite password' a term I'm just not aware of?

Comment: @AndrewBarber - It's not something which can be used in practices. It's just an assumption for "worse case". You can assume a password of 100MB as well. The procedural algorithm will not iterate over the entire 100MB if the password is strong enough, while the algorithm in Haskell may.

Comment: Ahhh, ok. I get what you mean!

Comment: And always consider what [xkcd has to say](http://xkcd.com/792/) on [password strength](http://xkcd.com/936/)...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right: if the password is already known to be ok, it will still try to establish the other conditions. Hence I would do it differently:

```
check passwd = go criteria passwd
    where 
      criteria = [(10, const True), (2, isUpper), (2, isLower), (2, isDigit), (2, isSpecial)]
      -- password is ok if at least 3 criteria have counted down to 0
      ok = (>=3) . length . filter (==0) . map fst
      go crit pwd
         | ok crit = True
         | null pwd = False
         | otherwise = go (map (trans (head pwd)) crit) (tail pwd)
      trans ch (0, p) = (0, p)
      trans ch (n, p) = if p c then (n-1, p) else (n, p)
```

The idea is to check on every character, if the criteria list indicates that the passwd is ok and return True in this case. Then check if the end of the password has been reached, in that case the passwd is invalid. And otherwise, we have not yet established all needed criteria, but have a nonempty passwd. Hence, we transform the criteria list by applying all functions where the counter is not 0 yet to the current character, downcounting successes, and recurse.

Note that `(10, const True)` encodes the condition: "Passwd is at least 10 characters long."

Comment: Looks like an elegant solution. The length of the password, however, is not a critical condition. It can be left unsatisfied if 3 other conditions are met, so "!!uuXX" should be a valid password. I think it can be implemented by somehow combining your solution with the way @Odomontois handled that (Using replicate and zip)

Comment: @darwish Well then you could check it at the end: if exactly 2 criteria are fulfilled, then the length must be > 9, if more than 2 are fulfilled already, the password is ok, otherwise it is not. Another approach would be to have `criteria = [(2, isUpper), (10, const true), ...]` and count downwards so that fulfilled criteria have 0 and are not checked anymore. - I will edit my post accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

A slightly more efficient version of your `atLeast` function is the `inBounds` function from `Data.Edison.Seq.ListSeq`:

```
inBounds i xs
  | i >= 0    = not (null (drop i xs))
  | otherwise = False
```

Comment: Thanks. I assume that `Data.Edison` is not a built in package, right?

Comment: No it's not. A similar function may be found in `Data.List.HT.Private` as `lengthAtLeast` - so it seems to be a utility function that is defined as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Check this. The idea is to have infinite list of successful checks to the moment.
import Data.Char

```
isValid password = let
    checks                      = [isUpper, isLower, isSpecialChar, isDigit]
    isSpecialChar c             = isPunctuation c || isSymbol c
    toInt b                     = if b then 1 else 0
    check c                     = map toInt $ map ($c) checks
    tests                       = zip [1..] $ map check password
    accum passed ((len,t):ts)   = (len,result):accum result ts where result = zipWith (+) passed t
    accum _ []                  = []
    valid (len,test)            = toInt ( len > 10 )  + (length $ filter (>=2) test ) >= 3
    in any valid $ accum (repeat 0) tests
```

Comment: This is an interesting solution. I have some comments about it:

1. Isn't is possible to use `foldl` instead of accum?

2. isValid "Uxxxxx" throws an error due to `Non-exhaustive patterns in function accum`

3. Since you `or` the checks instead couting them, your solution marks "Uxxxxx!" as a strong password. However, it should contain at least to special characters and at least two uppercase letters to be a strong one.

Comment: @darwish Updated solution and answer to your question is no - fold\mapAccum will force full computation here.

Comment: @darwish `foldl` always recurses infinitely on infinite input. This is not necessarily the case with `foldr` (compare the definitions of the two functions and try writing out a couple steps of the recursion to see why they are different in this regard), but the recursion in `accum` cannot really be changed into `foldr` (not directly at least) since the argument in the recursive call changes the list as it goes.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun, I thought I would throw together a very different answer to the other ones. The idea I had is to define a monoid that tracks statistics about a password, and a monotonic check on that monoid that the password is valid. First, some preliminaries:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving, StandaloneDeriving #-}
import Data.Char
import Data.Monoid
import Data.Universe
deriving instance Num a => Num (Sum a) -- this should really be in base
```

The statistic we'll track is how many characters we've seen matching each of your five conditions. Technically, we could actually track this in a data structure mapping functions to numbers, which is the purest FP way, but if done naively it's a bit inefficient. It's much easier to track if we have an explicit data structure to serve as the key in our map.

```
data Bucket = Char | Upper | Lower | Digit | Punctuation
    deriving (Eq, Ord, Show, Read, Bounded, Enum)
instance Universe Bucket

type Natural   = Integer -- lol, let's just pretend, okay?
type Statistic = Bucket -> Sum Natural
```

The `Monoid` instance for `Statistic` adds the counts in each bucket. Now, to connect the `Bucket` data type to the purer FP world, we'll have an interpreter to go from our "EDSL" into Haskell functions.

```
interpret :: Bucket -> (Char -> Bool)
interpret Char  = const True
interpret Upper = isUpper
interpret Lower = isLower
interpret Digit = isDigit
interpret Punctuation = isPunctuation
```

Using this interpreter, we can turn individual characters into elements of our statistic type. The source of this may look slightly intimidating, but in fact it's not much more than a bunch of conversion functions strung together.

```
statistic :: Char -> Statistic
statistic c b = fromIntegral . fromEnum . interpret b $ c
```

Up to here, none of the code actually had much "business logic" in it -- that is, exactly how many characters in each bucket we want to have or how many buckets we want to fill. So let's write down those two things. The former we'll just write as a statistic. Checking whether we've filled enough buckets is slightly tricky, so it deserves a bit of explanation. The idea is to iterate over all buckets, and leave behind a token if the bucket is "full" by comparing it to the thresholds. If we get enough tokens, the statistic is valid.

```
thresholds :: Statistic
thresholds Char = 10
thresholds _    = 2

validStatistic :: Statistic -> Bool
validStatistic f = length [() | b <- universe, f b >= thresholds b] >= 3
```

There is a critical property held by `validStatistic` that is not reflected in the type system. There's a lot of different ways to state this property; one way is to observe that `validStatistic f < validStatistic (f <> g)` no matter what `f` and `g` are (still pretending that there are no negative numbers). In English, this will mean for us that if some substring of a password is valid, then the whole password is valid, too.

Cool. Now we have all the pieces we need to check if a password is valid. What we'll do is turn each character of the password into a statistic; conglomerate all the statistics as we go; and check if the statistic ever crosses the threshold from invalid to valid (noting that if it does it will never cross back to invalid because of the critical property above).

```
validPassword :: String -> Bool
validPassword = any validStatistic . scanl (<>) mempty . map statistic
```

Try it out in ghci:

```
*Main> validPassword (cycle "UUxxxxxxx")
True
*Main> validPassword (cycle "!!xxxxxxx")
True
*Main> validPassword "!!xxxxxxx"
False
*Main> validPassword "!!xxxxxxxx"
True
```

P.S. Did you notice that `validPassword` is essentially implemented in the same way as map-reduce? (`map statistic` is the map part; `scanl (<>) mempty` could be a `foldr (<>) mempty` instead is the reduce part; `any validStatistic` would become `validStatistic` when used with a `foldr` and is the post-processing part) Makes it easy to see how to parallelize the computation of `validPassword` in case you really do have 100MB passwords. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use Monoids or Monad:

```
data Pass a = NotPass | TryPass Int | Pass a deriving Show

instance Monad Pass where
   return = Pass
   fail = NotPass
   NotPass     >>= _       = NotPass
   Pass k      >>= f       = f k
   (TryPass a k) >>= f = case f k of
              NotPass   -> if (a < 0) NotPass else TryPass (a-1)
              TryPass b -> TryPass b
              Pass  _   -> TryPass a

is_valid :: String -> Bool
is_valid password = toBool $ do
    TryPass 3
    toPass isUpper
    toPass isLower
    toPass isSpecialChar
    toPass isDigit
  where
   toPass bf = unless (bf bassword) NotPass
   toBool NotPass = false
   toBool _       = true
```